# Subtract arrays (Set Difference) with Google Sheets Filter

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I need to filter an array in google sheets to remove all elements of that first array from existing elements in a second array.

The arrays are always sorted, although the might contain duplicates. But to complicate the matter, the arrays are not ranges in the sheet (they are delimited text strings), and they are usually not the same size,  e.g. ***"a, b, d" - "b, c"*** ( should evaluate to "a, d" ).

**QUESTION PART 1**: The underlying logic I am using to implement **A - B** using FILTER and COUNTIF (just on ranges for simplicity) is

```
FILTER(A1:1, COUNTIF(A1:1, B1:1)=0)
```

But this fails for these test cases (should-be❌is):

```
{a,b,c}-{}⥱{a,b,c}✅
{a,b,c}-{a}⥱{b,c} ✅   {a,b,c}-{b}⥱{a,c}❌{b,c}      {a,b,c}-{c}⥱{a,b}❌{b,c}
{a,b,c}-{a,b}⥱✅       {a,b,c}-{b,c}⥱{a}❌{c}        {a,b,c}-{a,c}⥱{b}❌{c}
{a,b,c}-{d}⥱{a,b,c}✅  {a,b,c}-{b,d}⥱{a,c}❌{b,c}    
{}-{a}⥱{}✅            {}-{a,b}⥱{}✅
{}-{}⥱{}✅
{a,b,c}-{a,b,c}⥱{}✅
```

Should I be using another implementation, maybe with MATCH?

**QUESTION PART 2**: Since I need to use delimited texts instead of ranges, I am splitting my string with SPLIT(A1, ",") to get my arrays, but have to pad them and use array_constraint to get them the same size so that I can use the FILTER and COUNTIF functions, e.g.

```
ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(A1,REPT(",",999)),",",false,false),1,999)
```

Is there a more direct, not-so-intensive way to get arrays that will work in FILTER and COUNTIF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured this out after stumbling upon this sheet by Marc Meyer: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-beBOT1CjVyny7QwLz-RQCeN6fDTcIpLI1iZIjdTSgI/edit#gid=0

QUESTION PART 1: The underlying logic I am using to implement A - B using FILTER and COUNTIF (just on ranges for simplicity)
**should be**

```
=FILTER(A1:1, ISERROR(MATCH(A1:1, B1:1, false)))
```

and using this, I can have unequal sized arrays passed to it, obviating the need to pad and splice.